# Pasting Formula While Using Cell Reference in Pasted Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

I've been given an old calendar workbook.

It has direct cell references to other sheets to fill the spaces in the calendar.

I have been tasked to change these to show TBD when nothing is entered in the secondary sheet(s).

I've got the formula figured out: `=IF(REF=" ", "TBD", REF)`, so a cell which references secondary sheet R, cell A1 would look like `=IF(R!$A$1=" ", "TBD", R!$A$1)`.

However, there are dozens of these cells.  Pasting over them overwrites their original cell values, so I was wondering if there was a way to paste in the formula while maintaining not the cell value in the copied cell, but in the destination cell.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean if you paste the formula in `A2`, the formula should be `=IF(R!$A$2=" ", "TBD", R!$A$2)`? If yes, use relative instead of absolute adresses (i.e. remove the `$`

Comment: and copy and paste the cell not the formula. If you copy the formula string itself the references will not change.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad No, the cells in the calendar sheet don't match their references.  For example, the first calendar cell that uses a reference is D4, but it references cell A3 in sheet R.  The next entry is in cell F4 and references cell A7 in sheet R.  I want to know if there is a way to copy the formula in D4 to F4, but have the A7 reference replace the A4 automatically.

Comment: Then no there is no way for the paste to change the formula string to match.  The best bet is to use vba to parse the formula string from what is there to the new desired on using the reference.

Comment: @scottCraner, yeah I thought it might be something that would have to be done in VBA...I really need to learn that.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a formula to show `TBD`? Perhaps you could just use the cell's format? e.g. Right click on the cell and go to Format Cells...->Number->Custom and enter something like `General;General;"TBD"`. If the source value is numeric and formatted you'd lose the formatting or change General to whatever numeric format it should be if they're consistent but I suspect your source cells are text so this should suffice.